How to move search box in header
This is my current header.

I want to move search box to the left of minicart
I want to move the search box to the left of the minicart. This is my layout.xml.
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

<body>
    <referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="header.wrapper.content">
        <container htmlClass="header content" htmlTag="div">
            <container htmlClass="row" htmlTag="div">
                <container htmlClass="col-sm-8 col-md-6" htmlTag="div">
                    <container name="header.wrapper.left" htmlClass="header-wrapper-left" htmlTag="div" />
                </container>
                <container htmlClass="col-sm-8 col-md-12" htmlTag="div">
                    <container name="header.wrapper.center" htmlClass="header-wrapper-center text-center"
                        htmlTag="div">
                        <container name="logo.center" htmlClass="logo-center" htmlTag="div" />
                    </container>
                </container>
                <container htmlClass="col-sm-8 col-md-6" htmlTag="div">
                    <container name="header.wrapper.right" htmlClass="header-wrapper-right" htmlTag="div" />
                </container>
            </container>
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
    <referenceBlock name="logo">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logo_width" xsi:type="number">253</argument>
            <argument name="logo_height" xsi:type="number">48</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    <move element="logo" destination="logo.center" />
    <move element="top.search" destination="header.wrapper.right" before="-" />
    <move element="minicart" destination="header.wrapper.right" />
</body>

I tried inserting
<move element="top.search" destination="header.wrapper.right" before="-" />

However, the search box remains in the same place even after I run
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean



try this
@SavanPatel still no luck

I make change on layout.xml for both Magento_Theme and Magento_Search
On Magento_Theme
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="header.wrapper.content">
            <container htmlClass="header content" htmlTag="div">
                <container htmlClass="row" htmlTag="div">
                    <container htmlClass="header-col-left" htmlTag="div">
                        <container name="logo.left" htmlClass="logo-center" htmlTag="div" />
                        <container name="header.wrapper.left" htmlClass="header-wrapper-left" htmlTag="div" />
                    </container>
                    <container htmlClass="header-col-center" htmlTag="div">
                        <container name="header.wrapper.center" htmlClass="header-wrapper-center text-center"
                            htmlTag="div">
                            
                        </container>
                    </container>
                    <container htmlClass="header-col-right" htmlTag="div">
                        <container name="header.wrapper.right" htmlClass="header-wrapper-right" htmlTag="div" />
                    </container>
                </container>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="logo_width" xsi:type="number">253</argument>
                <argument name="logo_height" xsi:type="number">48</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
        <move element="logo" destination="logo.left" />
        <move element="minicart" destination="header.wrapper.right" />
        <move element="main.menu" destination="header.wrapper.center" />
    </body>
</page>

Magento_Search
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="top.search" destination="header.wrapper.right" />
        <move element="mobile.search" destination="header.wrapper.right" />
    </body>
</page>


@Patiphon Ongartittichai
Hey,
Use default.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- Move the search box to a new container -->
        <move element="top.search" destination="header.panel" after="logo"/>
    </body>
</page>

Feel free to ask all your queries until you feel they are solved. Thank You!
